# Clarifying the extent of the philosophy tag

Tags: support, tag-management, tag-wikis

A recent spate of vague questions under the tag [philosophy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy) suggests that it may be worth clarifying the purpose of the tag by ruling out a certain type of questions explicitly. These are questions that offer "vague philosophizing" rather than posing a question in the philosophy of mathematics. Such a change will not necessarily stop the vague questions but it may give a clearer justification for their immediate closure. Should a ban on philosophizing be explicitly included in [the excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/philosophy/info) giving the tag description?

Comment: The technical term is "excerpt".

Comment: I think what we want is to clarify the *extent* of the tag. (I made a minor edit to this question accordingly.)

Comment: OK, thanks, but should the excerpt state that this is not for vague philosophizing or something of that order? @AndrésE.Caicedo

Comment: I am guessing that @Andrés means that if we clarify the extent of the tag itself, then it will be much easier to determine the content of the excerpt. I'd expect that the answer would be "vague philosophizing is out of the scope of this website", in any case.

Comment: I agree that a clarification would be useful. I am not sure what the precise wording should be.

Comment: How about "this tag excludes questions that contain free-wheeling philosophizing"?

Comment: Maybe just a reminder: this is not an opinion forum, this is not a discussion forum.